# button gives BAD_EXE

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone SDK. I am using butting in my NIB file.Here is code :

```
[btnSelectCountry setTitleColor:appData.DataColor 
                       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnSelectCountry.titleLabel.font= 12;
```

I put Exception break point in my application.and i tried to crash so i can create good product.and it crashes.Exception break point gives me BAD_EXE on

```
btnSelectCountry.titleLabel.font= 12;
```

I don't know why it gives my BAD_EXE. because before BAD_EXE, it was working absolutely fine. never crashed at that point.

Comment: appData is my global variable.so you can take for ex :btnSelectCountry.titleLabel.font = 12;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set a font equal to a number. Notice that when you start typing btnSelectCountry.titleLabel.font into xcode, it will tell you that it expects a UIFont *.

So, if you want to set the font like that, try something like

```
btnSelectCountry.titleLabel.font = button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//use this code

[btnSelectCountry.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:15.0]];

//if it is working then check your appData property i.e appData.FontSmall;
```

Hope this will make you understand what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
btnSelectCountry.titleLabel.font= [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];
```

Try this. You gave size to type font.